# Extending/overriding jquery ui autocomplete functions

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using the jquery geo-autocomplete plugin to suggest locations as a user types (http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/).

Once user selects a suggestion, I want to edit a link on the page. I'm trying to extend the select function. I have defined a new select function to override core function. Here's a sample of the javascript:

```
$.widget( "ui.geo_autocomplete", {

// setup the element as an autocomplete widget with some geo goodness added
_init: function() {
    this.options._geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder; // geocoder object
    this.options._cache = {}; // cache of geocoder responses
    this.element.autocomplete(this.options);


    // _renderItem is used to prevent the widget framework from escaping the HTML required to show the static map thumbnail
    this.element.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(_ul, _item) {
        return $('<li></li>').data('item.autocomplete', _item).append(this.options.getItemHTML(_item)).appendTo(_ul);
    };
},

// default values
options: {

            select: function(event, ui) {
                alert('in override function');
             },
```

After a user selects one of the suggestions the alert appears and then text box is filled. I want the core select function to be executed (and thereby filling the text box), and then own my code to be executed (where i will change the href of a link). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not try something like this:

```
    options: {

            select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).trigger('change');
     },
```

Comment: I need to trigger my own function after a user has clicked a suggestion. Wont .trigger('change') call my function as the user first starts typing in input box?